# Conditional property in react/jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Is there a nicer way of doing the foollowing in jsx?:

```
let jsx;
if (description)
{
    jsx = <MyComponent id="1" name={name} description={description} />
}
else
{
    jsx = <MyComponent id="1" name={name} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultProps in "MyComponent". So you don't need to send "description" to component.

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  description: "" //Empty or something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the child component you could do

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/rkhayat/pen/amVOJE?editors=1010)

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
  var toReturn;
  if(this.props.description){
  toReturn =this.props.description;
  }else{
  toReturn = null;
  }
  return (<div>
     {toReturn}
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prepare description as an object you can pass it with the spread operator. For undefined values it will not show up.

e.g.

```
const desc = {
  description: 'Your description'
}
// description property set
let jsxWithDesc = <MyComponent id="1" name={name} {...desc} />;


const descUndefined = {
  description: undefined
}
// description property _not_ set
let jsxWithoutDesc = <MyComponent id="1" name={name} {...descUndefined} />
```